# React: Component's children should not be mutated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I've got this weird error that I've never seen on a react project (also meteor) and researched it to find nothing that could help me resolve it. Basically I get this error:

`Component's children should not be mutated.` on the 3 elements below on a component.

```
<h4>Team's defense: {defense}%</h4>
<h4>Team's offense: {offense}%</h4>
<h4>Team's total: {total}%</h4>
```

So basically I'm passing an array of `players` from the parent and use this list of players (props) to do a whole bunch of formulas like the below on the child component.

```
// PLAYMAKING RISKS
const playmakingRisks = Math.round((players.reduce((playmakingRisks, player) => {
  return playmakingRisks + player.playmakingRisks;
  // calculating below the total potential score of the team
}, 0) / (3 * numPlayers)) * 100);

// TOTALS
const defense = Math.round((duelTackling + fieldCoverage + blocking + gameStrategy + playmakingRisks)/5);
const offense = Math.round((kicking + ballManipulation + passing + fieldCoverage + gameStrategy + playmakingRisks)/6);
const total = Math.round((kicking + ballManipulation + passing + duelTackling + gameStrategy + fieldCoverage + blocking + playmakingRisks)/8);
```

The 3 `const` are already used in the state for a player view, so tried different things to see if it would fix it I changed the name of the variables for those 3 without success. I even checked all my variables with `console.log(typeof playmakingRisks);` to make sure they were numbers.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Can you post the entire code for you component?

Comment: Here is the full component: https://gist.github.com/mannyhenri/9673c94bc7b3907bdf612d3f004c8e5d

Comment: @JohnF. look above.

Comment: What version of react are you using? I remember seeing something similiar with values coming up with NaN causing this issue as addressed in this ticket https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7424 but it has since been fixed for version `15.4.0`

Comment: Ok seems like it's the problem and I will test once the official version is out. Thanks for you your help

Answer (score 1):

I see you're doing math calculations so it seems there's high likelihood that sometimes one of your values is `NaN`. Make sure it's not `NaN` and you'll be good.

You can read more here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7424